# Kafka mindset for scope information

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I work for a company that implement Kafka messaging for communication between several applications.
The main rule the IT as defined for the Kafka is : "*Kafka message only provide mandatory informations for futher sevices call*".

The idea is that we cannot provide the real informations about our event, only basic data to do query after receiving message.

For example :

`{     "eventID": "SHA",     "eventType": "Create",     "eventDate": "DATE",     "source": "SOURCE_APP",     "dataKey": "OBJECT_ID",     "dataScope":     {         "materialType" : "TYPE"     } }`

If I receive this payload, it's expected to use those info to build a GET call just after by using the "dataKey" and "materailType" to get all sort of metadata.
To my eyes it seem absolutely not sustainable.

In some case I have to retrieve a message with something like `OBJECT_LIST["A", "B"]` and then manually launch 1 get call for each object of the table.

I would imagine having in the message a simple object like :

`OBJECT_LIST[ { "id":"A" "quantity":5 }, { "id":"B" "quantity":10 } ]`

Nobody have a satisfying answer for this problem ; So someone could help me to understand this ?

Many thanks !

Comment: But what is the question?

Comment: OK maybe I wasn't really clear ! My question is : Does the rule to not include data onto the json payload of the message is a legitimate way to work ?

Comment: So there is no single answer, you should check the difference between event state transfer and event notification patterns, they are well described by Martin Fowler https://martinfowler.com/articles/201701-event-driven.html